# Invalid Endpoint in Clevertap

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, clevertap

I am having a problem in clevertap. I tried the test account that clevertap give in postman and it works.
but when I put my account id and passcode it shows **Invalid Endpoint**.

```
        $profile = [
            "identity"=>"jorem34.like@gmail.com",
              "ts"=>1419421212,
              "type"=>"profile",
              "profileData"=>[
                "Name"=>"Jorem",
                "Email"=>"jorem@gmail.com",
                "Phone"=>"+14153412312",
                "Gender"=>"M",
                "Employed"=>"Y",
                "Age"=>21,
                "Customer Type"=>"Silver",
              ]];

         $body = json_encode([
                'd' => [
                    $profile
                ]
            ]);
        $response = $client->request(
            'POST',
            self::API_URL,
            ['headers' => [
                    'X-CleverTap-Account-Id' => '*****************',
                    'X-CleverTap-Passcode' => '************',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ],
            'body' => $body
            ]
        );
```

Comment: @Joren Can you please post the API_URL used and the region of your account?

Comment: yeah. Youre right i already fixed it by adding the region into the endpoint @DhruvilVaghela